# Laravel Authentication with Passport,how send token Bearer in ajax header inside laravel project

Tags: laravel

I can get response from RESTful api when using Postman with Authorization Bearer + token.
 But How can I send request with token in ajax (i made it inside my laravel project).
[image]

Comment: Please put one space after Bearer. Your code seems fine

Comment: @AnoopPathak oh it is not my problem. How can I call Bearer token of user (replace question mark)?

Answer (score 0):

```
        $.ajax({
                url: "url",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': authorizationToken,

                },
                type: "post",
                data: data,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {



                },
                error: function (data, status, error) {


                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But where is authorizationToken? I saw token when login by Postman different from token in meta csrf-token.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
                 "X-CSRF-TOKEN":$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attractive('content')
                 "Authorization":"Bearer"+localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
});
```

Comment: You can set your  authorization token in localstorage like this ```localStorage.setItem('token', "Your Token");```